# numpy: get indices where condition holds per row

Tags: numpy

I have an array such as the following:

```
In [70]: x
Out[70]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

I am trying to get the indices per row where a condition holds, for example, `x > 1`.

Expected output is like `([2], [0, 1, 2])`

I have tried `numpy.where`, `numpy.nonzero`, but they give strange results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach -

```
r,c = np.where(x>1)
out = np.split(c, np.flatnonzero(r[1:] > r[:-1])+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [140]: x
Out[140]: 
array([[0, 2, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 2, 2]])

In [141]: r,c = np.where(x>1)

In [142]: np.split(c, np.flatnonzero(r[1:] > r[:-1])+1)
Out[142]: [array([1]), array([0, 1, 3]), array([1]), array([3, 4])]
```

Alternatively, we could use `np.unique` on the final step, like so -

```
np.split(c, np.unique(r, return_index=1)[1][1:])
```

Comment: @cosmos1990 Wrap it in a function, give it a fancy name and pretend its a built-in. There you go, it has become "simpler" :)